Memory Increase in PyTorch When Computing Second-Order Gradients in FNN
I'm working with a feedforward neural network (FNN) in PyTorch, where I need to compute second-order derivatives. However, I notice a significant increase in memory usage during each iteration, and the memory doesn't seem to be released properly even when using gc.collect() and torch.cuda.empty_cache().
I didn't observe this behavior in TensorFlow for a similar problem with the same architecture.
Here's a simplified version of the function where the memory increase occurs:
def compute_gradients(self, x, y, t, x_2D=None):
    x = x.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
    y = y.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
    t = t.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)

    g = torch.cat((x, y, t), dim=1)
    phi = self.ANN(g) 
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        phi_t = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=phi, inputs=t, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(phi),
                                    create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]
        phi_x = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=phi, inputs=x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(phi),
                                    create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]
        phi_y = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=phi, inputs=y, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(phi),
                                    create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]

    with torch.no_grad():
        phi_xx = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=phi_x, inputs=x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(phi_x),
                                    create_graph=False, retain_graph=True)[0].detach()
        phi_yy = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=phi_y, inputs=y, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(phi_y),
                                    create_graph=False, retain_graph=True)[0].detach()
    
    lap_phi = phi_xx + phi_yy
    lap_phi = lap_phi.detach().clone().requires_grad_(True)
    phi_t = phi_t.detach().clone().requires_grad_(True)
    
    del phi_x, phi_y, phi_xx, phi_yy, x, y, t, g
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    if x_2D is not None: 
        return phi, phi_t, lap_phi, phi2D_ann  
    else:
        return phi, phi_t, lap_phi


Memory Profiling Output:
I performed memory profiling, and here's what I observed (as example):
Step: Memory usage In FNN, RSS: 57554.89 MB, VMS: 78540.54 MB
Step: Memory usage before phi_t, RSS: 57554.89 MB, VMS: 78540.54 MB
Step: Memory usage before phi_x, RSS: 57803.39 MB, VMS: 78788.55 MB
Step: Memory usage after phi_yy, RSS: 58371.66 MB, VMS: 79356.55 MB
Step: Memory usage Out FNN, RSS: 57579.65 MB, VMS: 78564.54 MB

As you can see, memory usage increases after computing the second-order derivatives. I tried setting retain_graph=False for phi_xx and phi_yy as shown below, but this resulted in errors.
I want to know, what is the proper way to compute second-order derivatives in PyTorch without causing memory bloat or errors? Are there better practices for managing memory when dealing with higher-order gradients ?

please note that I already free th graph after backward .backward(retain_graph=False)

The memory is likely from the gradient tensors themselves. retrain_graph retains the intermediate graph to allow for backproping multiple times through the same graph - it doesn't cause the actual gradients on leaf tensors to be released

thank you , but I dont find a raisonnable reasons why these tensors despite liberated after each epoch, still cause mem increase
